# WEPopoverController view init warning

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad

I googled trying to find the answer, but failed.
It's actually a quick question, and i just don't have enough memory-management and objective-understanding to solve it properly by myself.

If someone ever user WEPopover library(great tool, thanks to developers https://github.com/werner77/WEPopover), they remember that there is a warning in WEPopoverController.m:

```
//First force a load view for the contentViewController so the popoverContentSize is properly initialized
contentViewController.view;
```

and the warning as follows:

```
Property access result unused - getters should not be used for side effects
```

I'm not pretty sure what are they trying to achieve, but i truly believe it's not a propoer way to initialize things, but i am not sure if i should use any methods, because i don't want to disturb the functionality.
Any advices and hints will be hihgly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved it, I had the same issue! :)

just replace `contentViewController.view;` with `[contentViewController view];`

That's all. You might solved it, as you've asked it a longtime before! But it would be helpful to other if they will find the same issue:)